# Добавить кнопки на каждое сообщение в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, button, href

Добрый вечер, такой вопрос, как добавить кнопку, которая будет отправлять GET запрос на контроллер, и у каждой кнопки в одном из GET параметров должен передаваться `id`.

К примеру так:

`site/index.php?r=site%2Fdelete&id=<id для каждого сообщения>`

`id` я получаю от другого контроллера, мне необходимо понять  как сгенерировать кнопку со ссылкой на `action`

Comment: <?= Html::a('Кнопка', ['/controller/action','id'=>5]) ?>

Comment: Вы это имеете ввиду? Это же есть в базовой документации. Удалите лучше вопрос

Comment: Нет, немного не то - это просто ссылка, а нужна кнопка, при нажатии на которую будет отправляться запрос

Comment: Ну тогда нужно как форму делать.

Comment: нужен аяксовый запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) вариант это делать формы  и делать Html::submitButton ( у формы может быть 1 кнопка ) указать у формы метод get , сделать hide input с параметрами
2) сделать кнопку ввиде ссылки  - что логичнее в данном варианте